# change the order in ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is one of my first apps in xamarin format. I need to modify a list order but I don't find the way. I need for it to be shown in order by `AutoModelo`. I'm sending you the source code in case someone could help me.

This is models/Auto.cs

```
 {
        public class Auto
        {
            public Guid AutoID { get; set; }
            public string AutoPatente { get; set; }
            public string AutoModelo { get; set; }
            public string AutoColor { get; set; }
            public bool AutoLuces { get; set; }
            public int AutoKmtablero { get; set; }
            public List<Actividad> Actividades { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

This is ViewModels/AutoListPageViewModel

```
namespace CracApp.ViewModels
{
    public class AutoListPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        string controller = Constants.AutosApi;
        public INavigation Navigation { get; set; }
        public ICommand NewAutoCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ViewAutoCommand { get; set; }


        Auto selectedAuto;

        public Auto SelectedAuto
        {
            get => selectedAuto;
            set { selectedAuto = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Auto> autosList;       

        //Collection = new ObservableCollection(Collection.OrderBy(x=>x.Date).ToList());


        public ObservableCollection<Auto> AutosList
        {

            get  => autosList;
            set { 
                autosList = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged();                               
            }

        }

        public AutoListPageViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            Navigation = navigation;
            NewAutoCommand = new Command(async () => await NewAuto());
            ViewAutoCommand = new Command(async () => await ViewAuto());
        }

        public async Task LoadData()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            AutosList = new ObservableCollection<Auto>(await AutoService<Auto>.GetData(controller));
            //Collection = new ObservableCollection(Collection.OrderBy(x=>x.Date).ToList());
            IsBusy = false;
        }

        async Task NewAuto()
        {

            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.AutoDetailPage   (new AutoDetailViewModel       (new Auto(),      Navigation)));
            //await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ActividadListPage(new ActividadListPageViewModel(new Actividad(), Navigation)));
             //await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActividadListPage(new ActividadListPageViewModel(new Actividad(), Navigation)));
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ActividadListPage());
        }

        async Task ViewAuto()
        {
            if (SelectedAuto != null)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.AutoDetailPage(new AutoDetailViewModel(SelectedAuto, Navigation)));

            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please mark/accept the answer which helps you so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yes, sure. Where on the page should I do it?

Comment: There should be an option to "accept" in your page.

Comment: Can you please mark the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the LINQ OrderBy

```
var sorted = autosList.OrderBy(a => a.AutoModelo);
```

in your context, probably like this

```
var data = wait AutoService<Auto>.GetData(controller);
AutosList = new ObservableCollection<Auto>(data.OrderBy(a => a.AutoModelo).ToList());
```

Comment: here?         public ObservableCollection<Auto> AutosList
        {
            
            get  => autosList;
            set { 
                autosList = value;
                var sorted = autosList.OrderBy(a => a.AutoModelo);
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                
            }

Comment: um, no.   That doesn't make any sense.  See my edit